# How to extract and modify individual p.table components from GAM fits in R

Tags: r, list

I have used a for loop to run a series of GAMs in R that regress a series of dependent variables on the same set of independent variables. I want to extract the p.table values from each model, but when I print the p.table objects from my list of model summaries, the p-values are absurdly long (~100 digits), and I cannot figure out how to apply a function to just that component of the p.table output while also printing the whole output.

Here is an example with `mtcars`. These model results are obviously meaningless; in this case, the p-values are printing fine, but in my data the p-values are way too long, and I want to truncate them in the printed output using, e.g., format.pval.

```
data(mtcars)
library(mgcv)

y_vars <- c("qsec", "wt", "hp")

models <- list()

for (i in y_vars){
  models[[i]] <- gam(as.formula(paste(i, "~ cyl + s(drat) + am + gear + carb")),
method = "REML", data = mtcars)
}

models_summ <- lapply(models, summary)

lapply(models_summ, '[[', 'p.table')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up assigning the output to a data frame and operating with it that way:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(models_summ, '[[', 'p.table'))
```

If anyone has more elegant solutions, I would love to see them.